# Is there an equivalent pip command for poetry?

Tags: python, pip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-poetry

I need to install a package with a flag using pip I run `pip3 install snowflakedb-snowflake-connector-python --no-use-pep517`

but as the project is using poetry to manage de dependencies how can I run the same as pip?

I tried `poetry add snowflake-connector-python --extras ["--no-use-pep517"]` but seems not reflect the flag that was used.

btw I don't find any related options reading the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add)

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3433

Comment: I haven't, this explain all.